# How to create Pandas bar plot with values from one column but filled (stacked) with values from another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like the one below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'decile': [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'conversion': [.3,.3,.5,.5,.5,.55,.55,.55],
                   'campaign': ['tv','online','tv','online','radio','tv','online','radio'],
                   'campaign_pct': [.6,.4,.5,.4,.1,.45,.35,.2]})
df
    decile  conversion  campaign    campaign_pct
0   1        0.30       tv          0.60
1   1        0.30       online      0.40
2   2        0.50       tv          0.50
3   2        0.50       online      0.40
4   2        0.50       radio       0.10
5   3        0.55       tv          0.45
6   3        0.55       online      0.35
7   3        0.55       radio       0.20
```

I want to create a bar plot with `decile` on the x-axis, the bar heights to be the values for `conversion`, and fill each bar with the proportion corresponding to `campaign_pct`, with `campaign` being in the legend. It should look something like the sketch below (the fill can be colors, doesn't have to be lines). How can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) / [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) :

```
(
    df.assign(val=df["conversion"].mul(df["campaign_pct"]))
        .pivot_table(index="decile", columns="campaign", values="val",
                     aggfunc="sum", sort=False, fill_value=0)
        .plot.bar(stacked=True, colormap="viridis", rot=0, ylabel="conversion")
);
```

Output :

[image]